# Using DAX for Production Planning

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, powerquery, capacity-planning

My question is based on building a ramp up for planning production lines.

I have a WIP where a ramp up category is selected to be used for each MSO (Master Sew Order).  The Ramp up is based on hour fences (for example 1-6 hours,6-12 hours,etc).

On the WIP, an MSO will have units (example 1,920 units), divided by capacity per hour (80 pcs/hr), to give time needed 24 hours.  This then needs to be 
calculated based on ramp up, for hours 1-6, 6-12, 12-18, and 18-24 and multiply our by related efficiency.

For example:

```
Hours 1-6: 20% efficiency * 80 units = 16 units/hr (6 x 16 = 96 units produced)

Hours 6-12: 40% efficiency * 80 units = 32 units/hr (192 units)

Hours 12-18: 60% efficiency * 80 Units = 48 units/hr (288 units)

Hours 18-24: 80% efficiency * 80 units = 64 units/hr (384 units)

Hours 24+: 100% efficiency * 80 units = 80 units/hr ((1920-960)/80)= 12 hours remaining

TOTAL TIME = 36 hours to produce
```

How would Power BI know to divide up the original 24 hour estimate into parts, multiply by respective efficiency, and return a new result of 36 hours?

Thank you so much in advance!

Kurt

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUhx9.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this in DAX but you tagged PowerQuery so here's a custom query that computes 36 based on your parameters:

```
let
  MSO = 1920,
  Capacity = 80,
  Efficiency = { 
    {6, 0.2},
    {12, 0.4},
    {18, 0.6},
    {24, 0.8},
    {#infinity, 1.0}
  },
  Accumulated = List.Accumulate(Efficiency, [
    Remaining = MSO, 
    RunningHours = 0
  ], (state, current) => 
    let 
      until = current{0},
      eff = current{1},
      currentCapacity = eff * Capacity,
      RemainingHours = state[Remaining] / currentCapacity,
      CappedHours = List.Min({RemainingHours, until - state[RunningHours]})
    in [
      Remaining = state[Remaining] - currentCapacity * CappedHours, 
      RunningHours = state[RunningHours] + CappedHours
    ]),
  Result = if Accumulated[Remaining] = 0 
    then Accumulated[RunningHours] 
    else error "Not enough time to finish!"
in
  Result
```

The inner lists for `Efficiency` are of the form *time-efficiency-ends*`,`*efficiency-value*. Plug in infinity to mean the last efficiency never stops.

In a normal iterative programming language you could update state with a for-loop, but in M you need to use `List.Accumulate` and package all your state into one value.

Answer (score 0):

In your data model you may have MSO in one table containing 2 fields, [Units] and [UnitsPerHour], and another table called EffTable which may store the efficiencies broken out by the hour fences.
Create 4 new calculated columns in your MSO table, one for each hour fence, eg [1--6]:

```
  =
6 * LOOKUPVALUE ( EffTable[Efficiency], EffTable[Hours], "1--6" )
    * [UnitsPerHour]
```

These are fields that hold how many units you would produce in the 4 time slots.  Create a new calculated field for the total, [RampUpUnits]:

```
=
[1--6Hours] + [6--12Hours] + [12--18Hours] + [18--24Hours]
```

Finally calculate the total time as:

```
=
24
    + ( [Units] - [RampUpUnits] )
    / [UnitsPerHour]
```

This calculates the number of hours required for the remaining units and adds it to 24 for the ramp up time.